# Make Half/Half shaded nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is very similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241511/how-do-i-make-partially-shaded-nodes-with-tikz-without-hardcoding-coordinates) question. I additionally need to be able to colour the second half of the node in any other color, preferrably via another pgf-Argument. I tried different approaches, all modifying the code below, but every single one failed in different ways. Could somebody enlighten me?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  prefix after node/.style={
    prefix after command={\pgfextra{#1}}
  },
  /semifill/ang/.store in=\semi@ang,
  /semifill/ang=0,
  semifill/.style={
    circle, draw,
    prefix after node={
      \typeout{aaa \semi@ang}
      \let\nodename\tikz@last@fig@name
      \fill[/semifill/.cd, /semifill/.search also={/tikz}, #1]
        let \p1 = (\nodename.north), \p2 = (\nodename.center) in
        let \n1 = {\y1 - \y2} in
        (\nodename.\semi@ang) arc [radius=\n1, start angle=\semi@ang, delta angle=180];
    },
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[semifill={gray,ang=60}] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462473. This answer makes use of `path picture` option.

Answer (score 5):

You could just do the same `\fill` path again (one with `delta angle=-180`, though) and use keys that get assigned a value:

```
/semifill/upper/.initial=none,
/semifill/lower/.initial=none,
```

where your fillings use `fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/upper}` and you could just do

```
\node[semifill={lower=gray,upper=red,ang=60}] {$y$};
```

but you'd need two times the calculations. I'll put in on one path.

Note the `\pgfqkeys{/semifill}{#1}` which evaluates your options (`\tikzset` is `\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}`).

The usage of the `to path` needs a target node (even though we don't even use it), hence the empty coordinate `()`.

Notice that – as in the linked answer – the semicircle is even under the border of the node which sometimes is noticable depending on the rendering.
We might substract the `\pgflinewidth` from `\n1` but we need additional calculations then.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=.1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  prefix after node/.style={prefix after command=\pgfextra{#1}},
  /semifill/ang/.initial=45,
  /semifill/upper/.initial=none,
  /semifill/lower/.initial=none,
  semifill/.style={
    circle, draw,
    prefix after node={
      \pgfqkeys{/semifill}{#1}
      \path let \p1 = (\tikzlastnode.north), \p2 = (\tikzlastnode.center),
                \n1 = {\y1-\y2} in [radius=\n1]
            (\tikzlastnode.\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/ang}) 
            edge[
              draw=none,
              fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/upper},
              to path={
                arc[start angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/ang}, delta angle=180]
                -- cycle}] ()
            (\tikzlastnode.\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/ang}) 
            edge[
              draw=none,
              fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/lower},
              to path={
                arc[start angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/semifill/ang}, delta angle=-180]
                -- cycle}] ();}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[semifill={lower=gray,                     }]           {45};
  \node[semifill={upper=gray,              ang=-45}] at (1,0)  {10};
  \node[semifill={upper=yellow, lower=red, ang=145}] at (0,1) {145};
  \node[semifill={upper=yellow, lower=red, ang=235}] at (1,1) {235};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also a very similar solution with `path picture` which avoids the problem of drawing right onto the outside of the circle.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a practice of `path picture`, see the PGF manual, Section 15.6; and also see [the above link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462473/140722) by @muzimuzhi. The default of the style is `gray!50`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}  % for [ellipse], [diamond], etc
\begin{document}
% see [path picture] in the PGF manual, Section 15.6    
% also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462473/140722
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill fraction/.style={path picture={
\fill[#1] 
(path picture bounding box.south) rectangle
(path picture bounding box.north west);
}},
fill fraction/.default=gray!50
]
        
\path[nodes={draw}] 
(210:1.5) node[fill fraction=yellow!50] (A) {AaA}
(-30:1.5) node[fill fraction=green!30,circle] (B) {BbB}
(90:1.5)  node[fill fraction,circle] (C) {CcC}
(145:2)   node[fill fraction=violet!50,ellipse] (D) {DdD}
(35:2)    node[fill fraction=orange!50,diamond] (E) {EeE}
(-90:2)   node[fill fraction=orange!50,star] (F) {FfF};
        
\draw[->] (A)--(B);
\draw[->] (B)--(C);
\draw[->] (C)--(A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```